# p:ajax getter for update being called before listener

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Here is my checkbox. I am preparing a comma delimited string of component ids in the listener. The problem here is the getter getUpdateComponentList() is being called before the listener is called. So the string is never updated.

```
<p:outputPanel>
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{form.colors}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{form.colorItems}"/>
  <p:ajax listener="#{form.testListener}" event="change" update="#{form.updateComponentList}"  />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's expected behaviour. PrimeFaces (and standard JSF) does not re-evaluate the `update` (and `render`, `oncomplete`, etc) attributes on a per-request basis. They are evaluated on a per-view basis. RichFaces, for example, does it in its `<a4j:ajax>` and yields exactly the expected behaviour.

For PrimeFaces, your best bet is to remove the `update` attribute and use `RequestContext#addPartialUpdateTarget()` or `#addPartialUpdateTargets()` in the action method instead.

E.g.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialUpdateTargets(updateComponentList);
```

It takes a `Collection<String>` such as `List<String>` or `Set<String>`.

By the way, that `event="change"` is unnecessary. Just use the component's default event.

---

**Update** for users of a newer PrimeFaces version who are reading this answer later on and can't find the aforementioned methods which are indeed removed in a newer PrimeFaces version; use one of the two `update()` methods instead (one takes a `String` and other takes a `Collection<String>`).

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(updateComponentList);
```

Comment: @Balusc, can you give me one exemple please ? !

Comment: because I can not found addPartialUpdateTargets method

Comment: @berber: It has been deprecated in PrimeFaces 3.2 and been removed in PrimeFaces 3.4. You need `update()` method instead.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for the correction.
but apparently this is not the solution that I was looking for :( because I get the same exception. which is `27 nov. 2012 17:55:24 com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException` ... can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem about 'update' getting executed before the 'listener'. Putting two 'p:ajax' -one with the listener and other with the update- did the trick.

In your case:

```
<p:outputPanel>
  <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{form.colors}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{form.colorItems}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{form.testListener}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="#{form.updateComponentList}" />
  </h:selectManyCheckbox>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: This works for me either. I wonder why BalusC way didn't work for me. Thanks :-)